# Bottom Navigation with Fragments or Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app with 3 layouts (1 list and 2 webviews) and one Main Activity with **bottom navigation**.

My first idea was drawn the 3 layouts (1 list and 2 webviews) into Main Activity layout and hide 2 layouts (webviews). So, when I push in some bottom navigation option, show that option and hide the others options.

But I thought to do the same with Fragments. The behavior is similar, but I have to created 3 Fragments and when push in some bottom navigation option, I should replace the Fragment option.

When I read another bottom navigation examples, it uses the first 'idea', but I think second idea is clearest.

How to use the bottom navigation? Activity with layouts or Fragments? Do you know another option?

Comment: Your choice, but using fragment would be the conventional way.

Comment: Fragments are better option as you can separate code. to implement it check this - http://www.androprogrammer.com/2016/12/bottom-navigation-view-with-fragments.html

Comment: I think so, fragment is clearest. But if I want to preload the 2 webviews content, would you use fragments or one activity?? I could preload webviews in the activity while it's hiding but I think I couldn't preload webviews in the fragments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used the Fragments approach as:

1. I can hide and show them.
2. It's clearest and I can separate code.

Answer (score 5):

It is up to you as @tahsinRupam pointed out. However, fragments are definitely the easiest to work with. An example would be something like this:

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.fragment_a:
                fragment = new FragmentA();

                break;
            case R.id.fragment_b:
                fragment = new FragmentB();

                break;
        }
        //replace fragment as necessary

        return true;
    }

};
```